# How to set the number of steps with adam-optimizer in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow training while using momentum optimizer in config file I can set number of steps.

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0001
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0001
          }
          schedule {
            step: 500000
            learning_rate: .00001
          }
          schedule {
            step: 700000
            learning_rate: .000001
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  **num_steps: 800000**
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}
```

But adam-optimizer doesn't have that option

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer: {
        learning_rate {
            exponential_decay_learning_rate: {initial_learning_rate:0.00001}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I control number of steps with adam-optimizer in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Num_steps seems to be under train_config, not adam_optimizer. It should work with any optimizer.

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  num_steps: 800000
  optimizer {
    adam_optimizer: {
        learning_rate {
            exponential_decay_learning_rate: {initial_learning_rate:0.00001}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It does not work, i have an arror: google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 92:5 : Message type "object_detection.protos.Optimizer" has no field named "num_steps".

Comment: @ARCAON sorry, I misjudged the depth. It should be the same as in your original example, under train_config.

Comment: Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality". Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.